# Pandas groupby day on sporadic days in a month returns wrong groupings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe whose index is a `DatetimeIndex`. I would like to group this dataframe by different frequencies (such as by day or by month).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={"values": [10.0, 20.0, 10.0, 20.0]},
    index=[pd.Timestamp("2023-01-02T01:00", tz="utc"),
        pd.Timestamp("2023-01-02T02:00", tz="utc"),
        pd.Timestamp("2023-02-03T01:00", tz="utc"),
        pd.Timestamp("2023-02-03T02:00", tz="utc"),],
)
```

which gives the following:

```
                           values
2023-01-02 01:00:00+00:00    10.0
2023-01-02 02:00:00+00:00    20.0
2023-02-03 01:00:00+00:00    10.0
2023-02-03 02:00:00+00:00    20.0
```

I'm trying to group by day using:

```py
groups = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="D"))
new_df = groups.apply(lambda group: 99)
```

What I expect is something like this, which should contain two groups, since there are two different "days" in the dataframe:

```
                           values
2023-01-02 00:00:00+00:00    99
2023-02-03 00:00:00+00:00    99
```

However, what I'm getting is this, with 33 groups apparently:

```
2023-01-02 00:00:00+00:00    99
2023-01-03 00:00:00+00:00    99
...
2023-02-02 00:00:00+00:00    99
2023-02-03 00:00:00+00:00    99
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Doing so by month via `freq="MS"` works and even yearly. However, by day I'm not sure what's happening.

Note that I'm not looking for a "periodic" kind of grouping, but rather just group values based on some frequency (like aggregate values for each day, for each 5 days, for each month, for each 2 months, for each year, etc.)

#### EDIT

The actual aggregation function I'm interested in depends on each group's first and last value:

```
def f(group):
    d = {}
    d['new_col'] = str(group.index[0]) + "/" + str(group.index[-1])
    return pd.Series(d)

new_df = groups.apply(f)
```

which raises the following exception (since not all groups have values):

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: I don't know if it's a copy paste error but your data is wrong. You have time values on creation of data frame. However the created data frame does not have time values

Comment: Yep, just the 00:00 times were missing, but in essence still the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).apply(lambda group: 99)` will create all intermediate days between the min and max value.

This is not incorrect, and you would see the difference if using a meaningful aggregation function:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).mean()
```

Output:

```
                           values
2023-01-02 00:00:00+00:00    15.0
2023-01-03 00:00:00+00:00     NaN
2023-01-04 00:00:00+00:00     NaN
2023-01-05 00:00:00+00:00     NaN
...                           ...
2023-02-01 00:00:00+00:00     NaN
2023-02-02 00:00:00+00:00     NaN
2023-02-03 00:00:00+00:00    15.0
```

You don't have this effect with `freq='MS'` since this frequency is higher than the maximal difference of successive values. You would see the same if one month was missing though.

```
pd.DataFrame(
    data={"values": [10.0, 20.0, 10.0, 20.0]},
    index=[pd.Timestamp("2023-01-02T01:00", tz="utc"),
        pd.Timestamp("2023-01-02T02:00", tz="utc"),
        pd.Timestamp("2023-02-03T01:00", tz="utc"),
        pd.Timestamp("2023-04-03T02:00", tz="utc"),],
).groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='MS')).mean()

                           values
2023-01-01 00:00:00+00:00    15.0
2023-02-01 00:00:00+00:00    10.0
2023-03-01 00:00:00+00:00     NaN  # March was missing and is created
2023-04-01 00:00:00+00:00    20.0
```

You can change the grouper to avoid this effect:

```
df.groupby(df.index.normalize()).apply(lambda x: 99)

# or
df.groupby(df.index.floor('D')).apply(lambda x: 99)

# or
df.groupby(df.index.to_period('D')).apply(lambda x: 99)

2023-01-02 00:00:00+00:00    99
2023-02-03 00:00:00+00:00    99
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. However for more complex aggregation functions, it looks tricky. Can you check the EDIT I just posted? In that case should I drop the NaNs (if that's even possible)?

Comment: Then try: `df.set_index(df.index.normalize()).groupby(level=0).apply(f)`